# change java version windows

Tags: java, eclipse, path, environment-variables

My laptop is 64 bit. But I have java 7 update 11(32 bit) for certain essential softwares. Now, i need java 8 (64 bit) and eclipse mars (64 bit) to work. I am unable to change version from java 7(x86) to java 8(64). I do not want to remove 32 bit java and also work with java 8, 64 bit.
I have included the path system variable contents. I am a beginner. will appreciate if you do not write GLIB and derisive comments.

I am not looking for any batch scripts answers. Can it be done using GUI?

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

My eclipse.ini

```html
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: If you want to use java 8 just from Eclipse, try editing eclipse.ini.

Comment: I have tried -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe in eclipse.ini

Comment: Try -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin

Comment: Note: The `-vm` and the file path must be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini. They must also be above any `-vmargs` line.

Comment: tried... but not working greg-449 and uoyilmaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added to eclipse.ini

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

but should

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

There must be a new line between. Are you sure you want to use JRE instead of JDK?

Try such an ini

```html
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: should i use C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe