# eclipse wont run C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

Tags: java, eclipse

I go to update `Java` and now `Eclipse` won't start up.  I have searched many different ways to fix this and nothing has worked.  It could not find the `vm` through `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`

Comment: Did you check that there is actually a java installed under that path?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026098/change-java-version-windows) help?

Comment: it is installed i believe path. javaw.exe is there. in \bin

Comment: so when i go into C:\Users\Kyle\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse\plugins i find org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642 when i click this the program runs fine but when i click the desktop icon it gives me an error. im slightly confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue sometime ago.
The version of the jdk might have changed due to the update. So I guess you reset the path variables using the current jdk path in the installation directory.

If it doesn't work,remove the bin part as you are setting the path variables. So you set the path variable to  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\

If am right, I guess what this does is , it goes and look for it in all the directories under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\

Hope it works.

Comment: so make a PATH with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

Comment: if that doesnt work edit the PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91 and if that does work. what should i do. this is all under the advanced settings in environmental variables.

Comment: so when i go into C:\Users\Kyle\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse\plugins i find org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642 when i click this the program runs fine but when i click the desktop icon it gives me an error. im slightly confused now.

Comment: I also dont know why that happens either. If you dont have much to loose, you can uninstall and reinstall everything back. OR why not delete the desktop icon and then send a shortcut of  the launcher or the application icon in the launcher directory to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look up whether java is really installed on that path.
2. Give eclipse the command line parameter

   -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe"

Comment: javaw.exe is in \bin

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the JDK into a *reliable* directory, i.e. "C:\JDK8", and install the JRE anywhere, i.e. \ProgrammFiles... This is because, the JRE will get updates frequently and therefore change its path. After that, open [Eclipse_Path]\ [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) and add the following lines:

```
-vm 
C:\JDK8
```